# Differences between Spring Boot and spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

just starting out learning Spring, could you tell me the main differences between Spring Boot and MVC? 
Which one is recommended for a beginner?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used Spring Boot but it seems easy to quickly get started with. https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: Copy/pasting your question into google gave this as a first result http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-vs-spring-mvc-vs-spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC is a project within the Spring Framework for implementing the model-view-controller design pattern. It is used to build dynamic (and static sort of) web pages and ReSTful webservices.

Spring Boot is an opinionated way of building Java applications. Using Spring Boot, you can build web applications using Spring MVC as well as other technologies. Spring Boot provides a common set of components and opinions for building whatever application you are aiming at.

If I put my educator hat on, I would recommend starting with Spring Framework sans boot, only because it will help you understand what boot brings to the party. That being said, I never write traditional spring applications anymore, and always use Spring Boot. The speed to market proposition of Spring Boot is why it is the defecto way to build applications today in enterprise, but so much is done for you that if you really want to learn Spring, you will miss out.